# How can i access my WebView from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a basic WebView:

```
const WebViewComponent = () => {
  function sendDataToWebView() {
     webviewRef.current.postMessage('Hello world');
 }

  const webviewRef = useRef();
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <WebView  
          ref={webviewRef}
          source={{
            uri: 'https://www.google.com/',
          }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Calling `sendDataToWebView()` works in this component since i have the reference. (useRef()).

But in another component:

```
const anotherComponent = () => {
      const webviewRef = useRef();
      webviewRef.current.postMessage('Hello world');
      
}
```

webviewRef is undefined.

How can i access my WebView from another component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this, with and without using name `ref` for the reference property.

1. Without using `ref` prop name, i.e. use any other name.

```
const WebViewComponent = ({ webviewRef }) => {
  return (
    <WebView
      ref={webviewRef}
      source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com/' }}
    />
  );
};
```

```
const AnotherComponent = () => {
  const webviewRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const test = () => {
      const run = "window.alert('haha');";
      webviewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(run);
    };
    setTimeout(test, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <WebViewComponent
        webviewRef={webviewRef}
        // ....
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

2. Using `ref`. This is possible using `forwardRef` feature of React. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

```
const WebViewComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <WebView
      ref={ref}
      source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com/' }}
    />
  );
});
```

```
const AnotherComponent = () => {
  const webviewRef = useRef();

  // .....

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <WebViewComponent
        ref={webviewRef}
        // ....
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't just create a new ref and use that in your `anotherComponent`. If you want to display the `webview` in your `anotherComponent`, you need to import it and return is as part of the `anotherComponent`.